Get data from Hardware Component to other package outside of ros2_control
I am currently writing a package that will calculate the linear acceleration and angular velocity (geometry_msg/Twist) for driving from A to B. I am now facing the problem of how to extract data like Encoder Speed, which is available in the Hardware Interface I have written, and get it available in my new package.
My question is whether there is a way to do it by staying close to ros2_control and using for example a state_interface or whether the easiest solution would be to just publish what I need to a topic? If using a state_interface would be the go-to-solution, how would I access said data?
I need data like Encoder speed for both wheels from my Hardware Interface, but need GPS Coordinates from my GPS Module which is simply a node.
EDIT:
I have just had a look at the different hardware interface types here and it seems as if a custom GPIO Controller would work exactly for what I am trying to accomplish.

I suggest writing a custom controller and pass the values as state interfaces. Joints vs GPIO is only a matter of semantic naming, in fact they are handled equally inside the ros2_control stack (except for: from jazzy on, joints have to be available in the URDF, GPIOs don't). Encoder values etc. would better fit to joints, GPS values as gpio (or even a TF?).
You could write a simple hardware component for your GPS module (see the demos for using several hardware components), or just use your node and subscribe to the topic (GPS update rate isn't that high I guess).
But we don't suggest adding a ROS node to the hardware component to avoid breaking the realtime loop, but to add a RT-safe subscriber to your controller.

Would it not just be possible to add a state interface to my hardware component and exporting the state interface from there? How would I then access the state interface in order to get the value?

This is exactly what I said.. if the quantity is a joint, export it as joint position. If not, then as GPIO, see this example here
